# Extract untrusted tarball safely in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tar

In the doc for [tarfile.extractall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) it says

> Never extract archives from untrusted sources without prior inspection. It is possible that files are created outside of path, e.g. members that have absolute filenames starting with "/" or filenames with two dots "..".

Some posts on the web or stackoverflow address these vulnerabilities, however, I can still think of another case, e.g. a tarball with following two files:

```
A --> /etc
A/passwd
```

Entry `A` is a symbolic link and anything under `A` will be redirected to `/etc`, which can't be detected by most of the solutions on the web.

My question is, besides this, there might be some other vulnerabilities I overlooked, so even if I had a piece of code that handles this, it might be still unsafe.  Is there a mature library of Python that can extract tarball safely?

Comment: Open in a virtual OS?

Comment: @stackoverfloweth, that's too heavyweighted.

Answer (score 0):

you can inspect the contents of the tar archive prior to serializing it with the `tarfile` library. For example, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html),

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", "r:gz")
for tarinfo in tar:
    print(tarinfo.name, "is", tarinfo.size, "bytes in size and is ", end="")
    if tarinfo.isreg():
        print("a regular file.")
    elif tarinfo.isdir():
        print("a directory.")
    else:
        print("something else.")
tar.close()
```